# Injecting dependency based on a value in config file

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I have a class which takes a configuration interface implementation through DI.

```
@Inject
private PRCConfiguration prcConfig;
```

There are various implementations of the PRCConfiguration interface. Currently it is injecting the default implementation. I wish to create a value in a config text file which will define what particular implementation of PRCCOnfiguration to inject.
I wish the @Inject notation to verify what value is in the config file, and based on that inject the particular implementation.

I believe we can annotate different implementation through qualifiers and then inject, such as

```
@Inject @NewImplementation 
private PRCConfiguration prcConfig;
```

But again i am injecting on compiletime through hard coding.

My config file would be something like

```
"injectconfig":"NewImplementation"
```

to inject the @NewImplementation implementation, subsequently if i want a different implementation to be injected. I could just change config file value as

```
"injectconfig":"DifferentImplementation"
```

and the  different implementation will be injected.

Is what i require possible through CDI?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [producer methods](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/beanscdi.html#_producer_methods) to achieve something like that.

Basically you just have to create a CDI bean which a method that returns the correct configuration instance and annotate it with `@Produces`.

Something like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfigurationProducer {

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public PRCConfiguration getConfig() {

        if( someCondition ) {
            return new NewConfigurationImpl();
        }
        else {
            return new OldConfigurationImpl();
        }

    }

}
```

In this case you should annotated both implementations with `@Vetoed` or you will get ambiguous dependencies errors. Using `@Vetoed` on the implementations will tell CDI that using the producer is the only way to obtain `PRCConfiguration` instances.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy!

Comment: Again +1 for the @Vetoed, would have spent hours debugging otherwise, but it only seems to be available in java ee 7?

Comment: Jboss is unable to find @Vetoed

Comment: In CDI 1.0 you can also use @Typed() without any values to get the same effect as @Vetoed.